# Check if partitions are aligned properly for performance?

Tags: partition, performance, gpt, parted, partition-table

I just created a GPT disk label for the entire space on my hard disk (`/dev/sda`) like so:

```
# parted

(parted) select /dev/sda
(parted) mklabel gpt
Warning: The existing disk label on /dev/sda will be destroyed and all data on this disk will be lost. Do you want to continue?
Yes/No? Y
(parted) mkpart primary 0% 100%
Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
Ignore/Cancel? I
(parted) quit
```

[Upon further reading now](http://rainbow.chard.org/2013/01/30/how-to-align-partitions-for-best-performance-using-parted/), I realized that 'ignoring' was probably a bad idea w.r.t performance.

But...

```
# parted

(parted) print
Model: ATA ST33000650NS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 5      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 1      2097kB  8592MB  8590MB                     raid
 2      8592MB  9129MB  537MB                      raid
 3      9129MB  43.5GB  34.4GB                     raid
 4      43.5GB  3001GB  2957GB                     raid

(parted) align-check optimal 1
1 aligned
(parted) align-check optimal 2
2 aligned
(parted) align-check optimal 3
3 aligned
(parted) align-check optimal 4
4 aligned
(parted) align-check optimal 5
5 aligned
(parted)
```

So `parted` has aligned the partitions by itself? `align-check optimal *` says so.

1. If that's not the case, how do I check if the disk's partitions need to be re-aligned for performance? And how do i go about doing that?
2. If that's indeed the case, `mkpart primary 0% 100%` actually automates the process of aligning partitions in all cases? Any edge cases where it wouldn't?

Comment: Modern disks are best aligned to a 4k boundary, IIRC, and many tools will align to 1M by default in order to allow more easily for abstractions like LUKS/mdraid/LVM. I'm not wholly familiar with `parted` output, but it does appear that the partitions there are misaligned at 4k. Meanwhile, the only way to realign the partitions is to delete and recreate them.

Comment: @TomHunt I just deleted all the partitions, and created a GPT disk label all over again by running `mklabel gpt`. So keeping alignment in mind, how should I run `mkpart` now?

Comment: I've only ever done this with `fdisk` or `gdisk`. They both handle alignment automatically by default, and it'll be aligned correctly so long as you specify partition lengths in large units (gigabytes, usually). I have no idea how to do it with `parted`.

Comment: @TomHunt I think `parted` does it automatically too. I've added details in my question to show the same.

Answer (score 4):

Starting `parted`with the `--align optimal` option tells the program to align to multiples of the device's physical block size to ensure best performance.

The `--align` option has other types available as well.

See `man parted` for more information.

Comment: What I don't understand is why, if I then use `mkpart primary 0% 100%`, the partition starts at 33.6 MB. That is a lot more than multiples of 512B ( Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B with Partition Table msdos )

Answer (score 0):

I just tested in a vm with centos 6.7:

```
# parted /dev/sdb 
GNU Parted 2.1
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label                                  
(parted) mklabel gpt                                                      
(parted) mkpart primary 1m 100%
(parted) quit                                                             
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.                           

[root@localhost ~]# parted /dev/sdb print 
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1074MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  1073MB  1072MB               primary

[root@localhost ~]# parted /dev/sdb "unit s print"
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2097152s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start  End       Size      File system  Name     Flags
 1      2048s  2095103s  2093056s               primary
```

so there you are, properly aligned gpt partition.